# Is it bad to return values from constructors?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Consider the following, simple class constructor. (note that I am obviously not including all methods that are referenced.

```
// Initialize User class.
public function __construct($user_id = NULL)
{
    // If user is loaded (and a user ID is provided)
    if ($user_id)
    {
        // If user is authorized.
        if ($this->authorized($user_id))
        {
            // Load user information.
            $this->info = $this->load($user_id);
        }
        else
        {
            // Return an empty (nonexistent) user.
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // If user is loaded (and no user ID is provided)
    else
    {
        // Create a new user.
        $new_user = create_user();

        // Return the new user's ID.
        return $new_user;
    }
}
```

My question is this: is my method of returning values here wrong? My friend insists that a constructor should ALWAYS return an object NO MATTER WHAT. However, the way I have it laid out here seems much simpler, and is much easier to work with. (If I am making a new user, then I get his ID right off the bat. If I am loading an existing user, I immediately have access to her/his information)

If it IS wrong, why? Why is this bad?

Comment: Nothing is "Always, no matter what"...

Comment: In PHP, return values have no effect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214724/php-constructor-to-return-a-null

Comment: Your friends advice is probably coming from a much different language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're trying to do simply doesn't work, the constructor *will* return the new instance of `User` anyway, even when you try to return `null`.

For example, this:

```
class User {
  function __construct() {
    return null;
  }
}
var_dump(new User());
```

will print:

```
object(User)#1 (0) {
}
```

http://codepad.org/0IdJydkY

Comment: The object is already created at this point, and `__construct()` is intended ONLY to modify the object's properties on creation.  When called on `new`, the return value of this constructor is simply ignored.  You can however do `$obj->__construct($user_id)` which will return `$new_user` value in OP's case.  But attempting `$obj->__construct($user_id)` is just bad though.  Very, very bad.  Never call a constructor method directly.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer I never thought of using `$obj->__construct($user_id)` directly. Very, very bad indeed! For starters, if one calls that, `__construct` will be running for a second time (since it already ran once on `new ClassName()`).

Comment: Right.  Although you can typically call PHP "magic methods" from outside a class, it's neither commonly used nor productive.  Even worse than an "anti-pattern".  In OP's case, this is very much "wrong".  A better fix for OP is to call a handler/wrapper function which either returns an object or null.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a static method to your class to create the user or to return null

```
public static function createUser() {
    // do your checks
    // if valid return instance
    // return null;
}

$user = User::createUser();
```

Note: You may have to make your `authorized()` method static - depends on the rest of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Your __construct() function shouldn't return any value at all, it always automatically returns the object - it should be used to initiate certain things.

I would recommend putting the code in a different function.

More on this can be read here: [Echo Return construct method;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254279/echo-return-construct-method)